# Laravel 5 - Share variables in Service Providers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to load something from database at the beggining of the request and can use this in every place of my application, just one query and full access.

Someone told me that I can do that inside ServiceProvider, but I don't know how, and reading the documentation didn't help me.

Can someone show me an example of how to share the `Config::all()` to gain access in all controllers and all views?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regarding `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`, if you place the following code within its boot method:

```
Config::set(['user' => ['name' => 'John']]);
```

Then anywhere in your app you can grab that value with `Config::get('user.name')`;

So you can feed a config with a result from an Eloquent model, just convert the result to an array.

Then of course you can create a `ServiceProvider` to deal exclusively with this.

Comment: That's just what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I recommend to you make a Middleware class. In middleware folder create a new class, lets say `GlobalConfig`. Each middleware class has a `handle()` method that receives a incoming request in order to modify it, or at your case do a specific task before it gone complete . At this point, you can share the data you want:

```
<?php 
namespace MyApp\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class GlobalConfig {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // asignning data
        view()->share('config', [1, 2, 3]);

        // let the request follows its flow
        return $next($request);

}
```

}

Well, as I said the middleware can **handle** an incoming request, but we need to specify when to handle it. There are two specific points when you can capture it:

#### 1. On every request

If you want to play with it on every incoming request, the you need to attach the middleware class into the `$middleware` array at `app/HTTP/Kernel.php` file like so:

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',
    'MyApp\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfig'

];
```

#### 2. For a specific route

If you want to apply the middleware class just for a certain route or routes you need to set an alias to your middleware class in the `$routeMiddleware` array at `app/HTTP/Kernel.php` file like so:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'globalConfig' => 'MyApp\Http\Middleware\GlobalConfig',
];
```

Finally, just add the alias each route you want:

```
Route::get('profile', ['middleware' => 'globalConfig', 'uses' => 'ProfileController@show']);
```

Comment: Simply superb. Just what I was looking for

Comment: Mind you, this only shares the values with the views, not the controller. OP specifically asked for a way to share with controllers as well.

Comment: @Rogier, I used `view()->share` for ilustrative purpose. You can grab the method you want. Remember, middleware are able to be used at **whole** application

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 4 Solution 
In Laravel 4 , you might handle this by simply doing this.
 
In your BaseController , 
Create something like this,

```
<?php

class BaseController extends Controller {

  public function __construct () {
      $this->beforeFilter(function() {
          View::share('config', Config::all());
      });
    }
}
```

Then you should do this in the controllers you want to share the data,

```
class ControllerYouWantToUseData extends BaseController {

   public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
     } 
 }
```

That is all to share the data in your views. You can use the variable in your views by just calling the $config variable.

Comment: You're sharing a solution that won't work in L5. The filter system has been replaced with [HTTP Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/middleware).

Comment: Thanks for correcting man. I think it might still help some people, not sure about deleting it. Any further comment is appreciated.